# Tensorflow 1.12 apply dataset.filter to dataset.window

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I have a sequential dataset from which I create windows in order to train an RNN. There are cases, where I want to throw away certain windows. However, when I use `dataset.window` followed by `dataset.filter` something breaks inside the pipeline. Here is a toy example, could someone please advise me on how to do this properly. This toy example demonstrates my issues. The below code creates windows of size 4 and then creates batches of 4 windows per batch. I want to throw away a window if the last element in the window is odd, so my batches will always be of size 4 but the windows inside the batch always have to end with an event element.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)
ds = ds.window(size=4, shift=1,
               stride=1,
               drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(4))

#*I want to keep the window if the last element in the window is even*
ds = ds.filter(lambda x: x[3] % 2 == 0) 

ds = ds.repeat()
ds = ds.batch(4, drop_remainder=True)
it = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
data = it.get_next()
for i in range(100):
    print(sess.run([data]))
sess.close()
```

And this throws the following error:

```
OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext_6}} = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[4,?]], output_types=[DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator_6)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OutOfRangeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-d6d959b5be78> in <module>
      1 for i in range(100):
----> 2     print(sess.run([data]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the return type of predicate in the [filter](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter) method, you need to return a scalar tf bool tensor, which I suspect is not happening with your pythonic predicate. Modifying the code to return such a tensor, gives me results.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(100)
ds = ds.window(size=4, shift=1,
               stride=1,
               drop_remainder=True).flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(4))

#*I want to keep the window if the last element in the window is even*
ds = ds.filter(lambda x: tf.equal(x[3] % 2, 0)) 

ds = ds.repeat()
ds = ds.batch(4, drop_remainder=True)
it = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
data = it.get_next()
for i in range(100):
    print(sess.run([data]))
sess.close()
```

Result:

```
[array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10]])]
[array([[ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [11, 12, 13, 14],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [15, 16, 17, 18]])]
[array([[17, 18, 19, 20],
       [19, 20, 21, 22],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [23, 24, 25, 26]])]
[array([[25, 26, 27, 28],
       [27, 28, 29, 30],
       [29, 30, 31, 32],
       [31, 32, 33, 34]])]
[array([[33, 34, 35, 36],
       [35, 36, 37, 38],
       [37, 38, 39, 40],
       [39, 40, 41, 42]])]
```

and so on